# Is there anyway I can find out if user uploaded multiple items in ItemAdded Event

Tags: 2007, development, event-handlers, event-receivers

I have a "ItemAdded" event, I want to check Number of documents uploaded if a user uses "Upload Multiple Documents" for uploading.

Normally what happens is when a user adds a item they are taken to "Edit/update Item" form but when he uploads multiple documents, it takes us straight to list.

Comment: do you want to restrict the user to upload one item at a time?

Comment: Nope, just want to check if item added is added through "Multiple document upload" option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any simple way of doing it, however you can save data to Database or something like that but its too much hassle so I avoided it.

Hope it helps if someone else came across same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with event receivers so forgive me if the suggestion is WAY off:

Couldn't you used the properties to check the current files in the document library for matching authors and created times? Seems to me the only way multiple items can have the EXACT same created dates/times and authors is if they were uploaded at the same time using the upload multiple files. (Not sure of the precision in terms of the created datetime field or if Sharepoint populates this field as they are uploaded or using the time all of them finish)

Comment: thanks but no thanks as I can't check something that is about to happen or if is happening :)

Comment: a smiliar question being asked - look at paul stork reply http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010general/thread/95802d54-348c-48a8-81e9-732575f75b3d